# NoClassDefFoundError exception

Tags: java

I got trouble in using my external jar file even if I put it inside class path correctly.

My external jar file is in the `D:` drive and my class path is `"C:\Program Files\Java \jdk1.7.0_51\bin; D:\webcam-capture-0.3.10-RC6.jar; C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\lib;"` so please help me solve the problem. Below is my code:

```
import com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class DetectWebcamExample  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
            if (webcam != null) {
                    System.out.println("Webcam: " + webcam.getName());
            } else {
                    System.out.println("No webcam detected");
            }

        } catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }            
}
```

the exeption detail is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam.<clinit>(Webcam.java:40)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:20)
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 2 more
Java Result: 1
```

i amend the path with "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;" and classpath "D:\webcam-capture-0.3.10-RC6.jar;." but the exception is still there

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What class is it failing to find?

Comment: The JDK bin and the JDK lib folders should NOT be in the classpath. Add e.printStackTrace() to your catch block (or even better, remove it completely), and paste the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: I concur jdk folders shouldn't be in the classpath, and usually not jdk jars either. But if you do need more than one entry in classpath do NOT put a space after the separating ; on Windows or : on Unix.

Answer (score 1):

Java has found `com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam` so you have successfully added that JAR to the classpath.

What's happening now is that `Webcam` is trying to use a `log4j` class, and that's not on the classpath.

This is common - package A needs package B; package B needs package C; and you can spend a while finding JARs to fulfil chains of dependencies.

In this case you're going to need two log4j jars - log4j-api and one of a choice of log4j implementation jars. See the log4j web page for details.

If the hunt for dependency jars starts getting silly, consider using Maven or Ivy to handle your dependencies for you.